# Comparing inequalities for Go bigInt?

Tags: go, biginteger, bigint, inequality, inequalities

I am trying to compare two big ints. I'm looking at the docs: https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int and I don't see an inequality operator, but I do see an equality one (Cmp).

How am I meant to compare a big int a to a big int b?
Am I meant to subtract b from a and compare the sign? Or is there something I am missing? E.g.

```
c := (new.bigInt).Sub(a, b)
i := c.Sign()
if i < 0 {
    fmt.Println("a < b")
}
```

It seems a little odd to me there is not an inequality operator, nor much about this online so I think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do, see if a number is greater or less than another? I'm confused why `Cmp` can't achieve what you want

Comment: Cmp returns zero if the numbers are equal, so they are not equal if `a.Cmp(b) != 0`

Comment: Please include syntactically correct, *runnable* examples with your questions. It's not really clear what `c := (new.bigInt).Sub(a, b)` is supposed to do here, but it definitely won't compile or run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cmp` returns: -1 if x <  y, 0 if x == y, +1 if x >  y

[Go Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/iCWySvS-vK6)